# rails 4 dry up controller with single render error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, dry

Maybe this is overkill, I but I am trying to use an after_filter to dry up this controller.  To my dismay, it is blowing up and I can not seem to figure out why.  To get it working, I had to add the render in each method.

Thoughts?

**Error Message**

> Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.
>   Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most
>   once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate
>   execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after
>   redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and
>   return".

**Controller**

```
class ErrorController < ApplicationController
  after_filter :render_me

  def javascript_disabled
    @title = 'Error! Javascript Disabled'
  end

  def system_requirements
    @title = 'Error! System Requirements'
  end

  def browser_upgrade_required
    @title = 'Error! Browser Upgrade Required'
  end

  private

  def render_me
    render 'error/system_requirements', layout: 'error'
  end

end
```

**Route**

```
  scope 'error' do
    get '/javascript-disabled', to: 'error#javascript_disabled'
    get '/software-requirements', to: 'error#system_requirements'
    get '/browser-upgrade-required', to: 'error#browser_upgrade_required'
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that render does not halt execution within your method. In your `render_me` method you call render, and then execution then continues in the action method being called ... which has an inherent render at the end of it.

You can fix this by calling your after_filter method yourself within each action and adding an explicit return to halt execution, like so:

```
class ErrorController < ApplicationController
  def javascript_disabled
    @title = 'Error! Javascript Disabled'
    render_me
  end

  def system_requirements
    @title = 'Error! System Requirements'
    render_me
  end

  def browser_upgrade_required
    @title = 'Error! Browser Upgrade Required'
    render_me
  end

  private

  def render_me
    render 'error/system_requirements', layout: 'error'
  end
end
```

Of Course you could DRY this up a little:

```
class ErrorController < ApplicationController
  def javascript_disabled
    render_with_error 'Error! Javascript Disabled'
  end

  def system_requirements
    render_with_error 'Error! System Requirements'
  end

  def browser_upgrade_required
    render_with_error 'Error! Browser Upgrade Required'
  end

  private

  def render_with_error(msg)
    @title = msg
    render 'error/system_requirements', layout: 'error'
  end
end
```

I tend to feel that if you need to monkey-patch the rails codebase, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: I just tried this and I still get the error: "Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".

Comment: My mistake - for some reason I had complete brain freeze and answered this as though it were an `before_filter`. I've updated my answer for you. I think it's better than monkey-patching the `render` method TBH.

Comment: oh, I like this a lot. Thank you:)

Comment: By the way `and return` in the end of method is senseless.

Comment: Yeah, true - a hangover from my initial badly written answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are already have implicit `#render` call in controller actions. So after filter calls `#render` once again explicitly and you get a DoubleRenderError.

You can override `#render` method like that

```
def render(*args)
  if args.blank? && !block_given?
    # default template
    super('error/system_requirements', layout: 'error')
  else
    super
  end
end
```

I think it's better than using callbacks aka filters.

Comment: this is a pretty crazy approach.  I wonder if other devs would abuse that but I like that solution. hmmmm...

Comment: As I said in my answer, if you're monkey-patching the rails codebase, I think you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: It is not a monkey patch. It is Ruby. It is inheritance. Rails does not provide you ability to set default view for controller but Ruby does.

Comment: @FlashGordon `Rails does not provide you ability to set default view for controller` this wrong. [AbstractController#append_view_path](http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/ViewPaths/append_view_path)

Comment: @Зелёный Ok. Could you post a gist with example?

Comment: what example you need? this normal practice.

Answer (score 0):

In case others find this post, here is another approach you can take to dry it up:

```
class ErrorController < ApplicationController

  def javascript_disabled
    @title = 'Error! Javascript Disabled'
    render_it
  end

  def system_requirements
    @title = 'Error! System Requirements'
    render_it
  end

  def browser_upgrade_required
    @title = 'Error! Browser Upgrade Required'
    render_it
  end

  private

  def render_it
    render 'error/system_requirements', layout: 'error'
  end

end
```